# React.js: Heroku: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/src/client/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

My apologies if this is not the correct way to do this. I have spent 4 days on this problem and eventually figured out a solution I would just like to post this possible solution if anyone else encounters this problem.

I am running a Node.js server with the React client inside of it here is an image of folder structure for reference.

[image: Folder Structure]

I use a postbuild script in package.json to build my project on heroku

For reasons that are beyond me the following GET catch all statement

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
});
```

Path was returning '/app/src/client/build/index.html' this is the incorrect path as your app is hosted on /app/client/build/index.html I had to edit my GET catch all statement to the following.

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve("client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

It now correctly redirects to my index file and the app works correctly. Like I said unfortunately I cant advise on why the __dirname is not pointing to the right folder so if anyone could shed light on that will be great.

Also the robustness of the solution could be a problem as should Heroku change file structures the GET catch all statement could break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__dirname` returns the path to the folder containing the executed file.

So if the code containing `__dirname` is in the file '/app/src/app.js', `__dirname` will resolve as '/app/src'.
If your `__dirname` is in the file '/app/foo/bar/baz.js', it will resolve as '/app/foo/bar'.

Since you want your path to resolve as '/app/client/...' your fix is good.

The solution you used should be robust enough. `path.resolve()` will set your working directory (the one where you run your app, so '/app' on heroku I assume) as the root of your path. So unless you change your directory names or move files, you should be OK.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!! It is amazing that I was not able to find this noted anywhere. I guess its the problem when you are a total beginner you don't understand exactly how the commands work. My fault for re-organizing the file structure.